# Provide additional classpath on jar having embedded Tomcat

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I have a executable jar containing an embedded Tomcat which is created thanks to tomcat7-maven-plugin: tomcat7:exec-war.

I need to provide an additional classpath for some Jar because I cannot include them directly in my executable Jar. How can I provide this classpath ?

- I cannot execute `export CLASSPATH` before I launch my executable Jar because `catalina.sh/.bat` erase the `CLASSPATH` value.
- I cannot provide a `setenv.sh/.bat` because the executable Jar is created by the maven plugin.
- I cannot update property `common.loader` from `catalina.properties` because I don't have control on this file which is generated by maven plugin.

Note: I don't want to specify a hardcoded path to the lib in the executable Jar.

Answer (score 0):

Actually whatever jar files are inside WAR file at WEB-INF/lib are in classpath for WAR file classloader.
 So, you can package your additional jar into war.
I'm not familiar with maven tomcat plugin, but just look to its options. It must have ability to put additional jars into war file (maybe just through dependencies in `compile` or 'runtime` scope. It is a standard feature.

If your additional jar must be outside of war you have to give it in system classpath for Java when you run your executable jar (through -cp parameter, I guess). Or you can define path to it in the MANIFEST.MF file of your jar.

Comment: Thanks but my additional jar must be outside the war/executable jar. I think -cp is ignored when we use it with -jar. I've tried and it doesn't seams to work. Moreover, I don't want to specified an hardcoded path to the lib in MANIFEST.MF (question updated).